# Показать/скрыть блок/и при нажатии, на странице FAQ

Tags: javascript

Необходимо отфильтровать блоки при нажатии на кнопку (кнопка 1 - блок 1, кнопка 2 - блок 2 и тд).
Пробую показать соответствующий блок функцией show, но это не работает.
Помогите с идеями?!

```js
// show/hide content when title is clicked
$('.faq-main-container .faq-main-question').click(function() {
 
  // check to see if faq-block already has open on it then remove class
  if ($(this).next('.faq-block').hasClass('open')) {
    // then don't display content
    $(this).next('.faq-block').removeClass('open');
  } else {
     // close all content blocks
     $('.faq-block').removeClass('open');
   // open content block associated with h2 clicked
  $(this).next('.faq-block').addClass('open');
 }
  
});

// BEGIN SEARCH FILTER

var keyWord = "no is sense cat foot game same delicious".split(" ");

// watch for any changes in input field and when changes perform function
$('#search-field').on('propertychange input', function() {
  
 // convert input in search field to lowercase
 var inputValue = $(this).val().toLowerCase(); 
  
  // don't search placeholder
   if ($('#search-field').val() === "Type Word In Here") {
    inputValue = '';
   }
  
  // detect if user is searching
  if (inputValue) {
    // hide main FAQ titles
   $('.faq-title').hide();
    // show all questions
   $('.faq-main-container').show();
  } else {
    // clear function performed
   clearSearch();
  }
  
  // link word match to search field input
   // take all text entered into input and seperate as items in an array
   var searchWords = inputValue.split(" ");
   // creare an empty array
   var searchArray = [];
   // iterate over the items in the array
   for (var i = 0; i < searchWords.length; i++) {
      // return index number of term that matches an item in keyWord array
    var wordMatch = $.inArray(searchWords[i], keyWord);
      // not matched terms return -1 so if greater than -1 add term to searchArray
    if(wordMatch > -1) {
        // push index item from keyWord array based on wordMatch index number
     searchArray.push(keyWord[wordMatch]);
    }
  }; 
  
  // match h2 to search field input
   // iterate through each list item
    $('.faq-main-container > ul > li > .faq-main-block > .faq-main-question').each(function() {
      // grab all of the title and content text and convert to lowercase
      var hValue = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
      // return index number - -1 if not found - of input value from user that matches any of text 
      if( hValue.search(inputValue) >= 0) {
        // show title and content that matches
       $(this).show();
      } else {
        // iterate over searchArray array
       for(var i = 0; i < searchArray.length; i++) {
          // return index number - -1 if not found - of searchArray that matches hValue
        var match = hValue.search(searchArray[i]);
          // if index is greater than -1 then stop iterating since match/matches have been found
        if(match >= 0){break};
       }
        // if index is greater than -1...
       if (match >= 0) {
          // show title and text
        $(this).show();
       } else {
          // hide title and text
        $(this).hide();
       }
      }; 
   });
  
  // no matches then clear search
   // if li has no content visible then... - :visible is a selector and elements are considered visible if they consume space in the document. Visible elements have a width or height that is greater than zero.
    if($('.faq-main-container li .faq-main-question:visible').length === 0) {
      // show clear search button and text
      $('#no-information-container').show();
    } else {
      // hide clear search button and text
      $('#no-information-container').hide();
    }

});

$("#clear-button").click(function() {
 clearSearch();
});
$("#clear-button_all").click(function() {
 clearSearch();
});
$("#button_1").click(function() {
  $('.faq-main-container-button-2').show();
});

// clear search function
var clearSearch = function() {
  // if something other than placeholder is entered into input
  if ($('#search-field').val() && $('#search-field').val() !== "What can we help you find?") {
    // clear search input
    $('#search-field').val("");
    // display all h2 titles as before search
    $('#search-field').trigger('propertychange');
  }
  // show heading titles when search input is cleared
  $('.faq-title').show();
}
```

```css
.faq{padding:40px 0;}
/*SEARCH FUNCTION*/
#search-field {outline: none;display: inline-block;border:1px solid #787878;border-radius:20px;width:50%;padding:5px 10px;margin-top:20px;}
.faq {margin-bottom: 40px;font-family: MyriadProLight, sans-serif;color: #787878;font-size: 21px;}
.faq ul{list-style: none;}
/*FAQ CONTAINERS*/
.faq-main-container .faq-main-question {cursor: pointer;}
.faq-main-container .faq-title {cursor: pointer;}
.faq-main-container .faq-main-question>span>span{color:#00aae3;}
.faq-main-container .faq-main-question span:hover {border-bottom:1px dashed #787878;}
.faq-main-block,.faq-block{margin-left:20px;}
.faq-block {max-height: 0px;overflow: hidden;transition-property: all;transition-duration: 1s;transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);}
/* allows conent to be displayed */
.open {max-height: 500px;}
/*NO INFORMATION PAGE*/
#no-information-container {display:none;}
#no-information-found {text-align: center;}
#no-information {position: relative;display:inline-block;font-size: 24px;color: #2ba6cb;}
#clear-button {display: block;margin-top: 20px;}
#clear-button_all,#button-1,#button-2,#button-3 {padding:5px 10px;border-radius:20px;text-transform:uppercase;margin-top:20px;}
#clear-button_all {background:#00aae3;border:1px solid #00aae3;color:#fff;}
#clear-button_all:hover {background:#007fa9;border:1px solid #007fa9;-webkit-transition:all 500ms ease-in-out;transition:all 500ms ease-in-out;}
#button-1,#button-2,#button-3 {border:1px solid #787878;color:#787878;}
#button-1:hover,#button-2:hover,#button-3:hover {border:1px solid #a42187;background:#a42187;color:#fff;-webkit-transition:all 300ms ease-in-out;transition:all 300ms ease-in-out;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="faq">
  <div class="container">
  <div class="blue_hdr big_hdr bold_hdr">Frequently asked questions</div>
  <div id="search-container">
   <button id="clear-button_all">ALL questions</button>
   <button id="button-1">Button 1</button>
   <button id="button-2">Button 2</button>
   <button id="button-3">Button 3</button>
  </div>
  <div id="search-container">
   <input id="search-field" type="search" placeholder="search what you need"/>
  </div>

  <!-- PAGE 1 : Gender FAQ's -->
  <div class="faq-main-container faq-main-container-button-1">
   <ul>
    <li>
    <h2 class="faq-title blue_hdr">1. Title 1</h2>
    
    <div class="faq-main-block">
     <div class="faq-main-question"><span><span>1.1.</span> Question 1.1. General Provisions</span></div>
     <div class="faq-block">
     <div class="gender-faq-inner-block">
     <div class="gender-faq-content">
      <ul class="gender-faq-content">
      <li>Answer 1.1.</li>
      <li>These Terms shall be governed and construed in accordance with the laws of Delaware, United States, without regard to its conflict of law provisions.</li>
      <li>Our failure to enforce any right or provision of these Terms will not be considered a waiver of those rights. If any provision of these Terms is held to be invalid or unenforceable by a court, the remaining provisions of these Terms will remain in effect. These Terms constitute the entire agreement between us regarding our Service, and supersede and replace any prior agreements we might have had between us regarding the Service.</li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="faq-main-block">
     <div class="faq-main-question"><span><span>1.2.</span> Question 1.2. General Provisions</span></div>
     <div class="faq-block">
     <div class="gender-faq-inner-block">
     <div class="gender-faq-content">
      <ul class="gender-faq-content">
      <li>Answer 1.1.</li>
      <li>These Terms shall be governed and construed in accordance with the laws of Delaware, United States, without regard to its conflict of law provisions.</li>
      <li>Our failure to enforce any right or provision of these Terms will not be considered a waiver of those rights. If any provision of these Terms is held to be invalid or unenforceable by a court, the remaining provisions of these Terms will remain in effect. These Terms constitute the entire agreement between us regarding our Service, and supersede and replace any prior agreements we might have had between us regarding the Service.</li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="faq-main-block">
     <div class="faq-main-question"><span><span>1.3.</span> Question 1.3. General Provisions</span></div>
     <div class="faq-block">
     <div class="gender-faq-inner-block">
     <div class="gender-faq-content">
      <ul class="gender-faq-content">
      <li>Answer 1.1.</li>
      <li>These Terms shall be governed and construed in accordance with the laws of Delaware, United States, without regard to its conflict of law provisions.</li>
      <li>Our failure to enforce any right or provision of these Terms will not be considered a waiver of those rights. If any provision of these Terms is held to be invalid or unenforceable by a court, the remaining provisions of these Terms will remain in effect. These Terms constitute the entire agreement between us regarding our Service, and supersede and replace any prior agreements we might have had between us regarding the Service.</li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="faq-main-block">
     <div class="faq-main-question"><span><span>1.4.</span> Question 1.4. General Provisions</span></div>
     <div class="faq-block">
     <div class="gender-faq-inner-block">
     <div class="gender-faq-content">
      <ul class="gender-faq-content">
      <li>Answer 1.1.</li>
      <li>These Terms shall be governed and construed in accordance with the laws of Delaware, United States, without regard to its conflict of law provisions.</li>
      <li>Our failure to enforce any right or provision of these Terms will not be considered a waiver of those rights. If any provision of these Terms is held to be invalid or unenforceable by a court, the remaining provisions of these Terms will remain in effect. These Terms constitute the entire agreement between us regarding our Service, and supersede and replace any prior agreements we might have had between us regarding the Service.</li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="faq-main-block">
     <div class="faq-main-question"><span><span>1.5.</span> Question 1.5. General Provisions</span></div>
     <div class="faq-block">
     <div class="gender-faq-inner-block">
     <div class="gender-faq-content">
      <ul class="gender-faq-content">
      <li>Answer 1.1.</li>
      <li>These Terms shall be governed and construed in accordance with the laws of Delaware, United States, without regard to its conflict of law provisions.</li>
      <li>Our failure to enforce any right or provision of these Terms will not be considered a waiver of those rights. If any provision of these Terms is held to be invalid or unenforceable by a court, the remaining provisions of these Terms will remain in effect. These Terms constitute the entire agreement between us regarding our Service, and supersede and replace any prior agreements we might have had between us regarding the Service.</li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="faq-main-block">
     <div class="faq-main-question"><span><span>1.6.</span> Question 1.6. General Provisions</span></div>
     <div class="faq-block">
     <div class="gender-faq-inner-block">
     <div class="gender-faq-content">
      <ul class="gender-faq-content">
      <li>Answer 1.1.</li>
      <li>These Terms shall be governed and construed in accordance with the laws of Delaware, United States, without regard to its conflict of law provisions.</li>
      <li>Our failure to enforce any right or provision of these Terms will not be considered a waiver of those rights. If any provision of these Terms is held to be invalid or unenforceable by a court, the remaining provisions of these Terms will remain in effect. These Terms constitute the entire agreement between us regarding our Service, and supersede and replace any prior agreements we might have had between us regarding the Service.</li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="faq-main-block">
     <div class="faq-main-question"><span><span>1.7.</span> Question 1.7. General Provisions</span></div>
     <div class="faq-block">
     <div class="gender-faq-inner-block">
     <div class="gender-faq-content">
      <ul class="gender-faq-content">
      <li>Answer 1.1.</li>
      <li>These Terms shall be governed and construed in accordance with the laws of Delaware, United States, without regard to its conflict of law provisions.</li>
      <li>Our failure to enforce any right or provision of these Terms will not be considered a waiver of those rights. If any provision of these Terms is held to be invalid or unenforceable by a court, the remaining provisions of these Terms will remain in effect. These Terms constitute the entire agreement between us regarding our Service, and supersede and replace any prior agreements we might have had between us regarding the Service.</li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="faq-main-block">
     <div class="faq-main-question"><span><span>1.8.</span> Question 1.8. General Provisions</span></div>
     <div class="faq-block">
     <div class="gender-faq-inner-block">
     <div class="gender-faq-content">
      <ul class="gender-faq-content">
      <li>Answer 1.1.</li>
      <li>These Terms shall be governed and construed in accordance with the laws of Delaware, United States, without regard to its conflict of law provisions.</li>
      <li>Our failure to enforce any right or provision of these Terms will not be considered a waiver of those rights. If any provision of these Terms is held to be invalid or unenforceable by a court, the remaining provisions of these Terms will remain in effect. These Terms constitute the entire agreement between us regarding our Service, and supersede and replace any prior agreements we might have had between us regarding the Service.</li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- PAGE 2 : Sport FAQ's -->
  <div class="faq-main-container faq-main-container-button-2">
   <ul>
    <li>
    <h2 class="faq-title blue_hdr">2. Title 2</h2>
    
    <div class="faq-main-block">
     <div class="faq-main-question"><span><span>2.1.</span> Question 2.1. General Provisions</span></div>
     <div class="faq-block">
     <div class="gender-faq-inner-block">
     <div class="gender-faq-content">
      <ul class="gender-faq-content">
      <li>Answer 1.1.</li>
      <li>These Terms shall be governed and construed in accordance with the laws of Delaware, United States, without regard to its conflict of law provisions.</li>
      <li>Our failure to enforce any right or provision of these Terms will not be considered a waiver of those rights. If any provision of these Terms is held to be invalid or unenforceable by a court, the remaining provisions of these Terms will remain in effect. These Terms constitute the entire agreement between us regarding our Service, and supersede and replace any prior agreements we might have had between us regarding the Service.</li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="faq-main-block">
     <div class="faq-main-question"><span><span>2.2.</span> Question 2.2. General Provisions</span></div>
     <div class="faq-block">
     <div class="gender-faq-inner-block">
     <div class="gender-faq-content">
      <ul class="gender-faq-content">
      <li>Answer 1.1.</li>
      <li>These Terms shall be governed and construed in accordance with the laws of Delaware, United States, without regard to its conflict of law provisions.</li>
      <li>Our failure to enforce any right or provision of these Terms will not be considered a waiver of those rights. If any provision of these Terms is held to be invalid or unenforceable by a court, the remaining provisions of these Terms will remain in effect. These Terms constitute the entire agreement between us regarding our Service, and supersede and replace any prior agreements we might have had between us regarding the Service.</li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="faq-main-block">
     <div class="faq-main-question"><span><span>2.3.</span> Question 2.3. General Provisions</span></div>
     <div class="faq-block">
     <div class="gender-faq-inner-block">
     <div class="gender-faq-content">
      <ul class="gender-faq-content">
      <li>Answer 1.1.</li>
      <li>These Terms shall be governed and construed in accordance with the laws of Delaware, United States, without regard to its conflict of law provisions.</li>
      <li>Our failure to enforce any right or provision of these Terms will not be considered a waiver of those rights. If any provision of these Terms is held to be invalid or unenforceable by a court, the remaining provisions of these Terms will remain in effect. These Terms constitute the entire agreement between us regarding our Service, and supersede and replace any prior agreements we might have had between us regarding the Service.</li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="faq-main-block">
     <div class="faq-main-question"><span><span>2.4.</span> Question 2.4. General Provisions</span></div>
     <div class="faq-block">
     <div class="gender-faq-inner-block">
     <div class="gender-faq-content">
      <ul class="gender-faq-content">
      <li>Answer 1.1.</li>
      <li>These Terms shall be governed and construed in accordance with the laws of Delaware, United States, without regard to its conflict of law provisions.</li>
      <li>Our failure to enforce any right or provision of these Terms will not be considered a waiver of those rights. If any provision of these Terms is held to be invalid or unenforceable by a court, the remaining provisions of these Terms will remain in effect. These Terms constitute the entire agreement between us regarding our Service, and supersede and replace any prior agreements we might have had between us regarding the Service.</li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="faq-main-block">
     <div class="faq-main-question"><span><span>2.5.</span> Question 2.5. General Provisions</span></div>
     <div class="faq-block">
     <div class="gender-faq-inner-block">
     <div class="gender-faq-content">
      <ul class="gender-faq-content">
      <li>Answer 1.1.</li>
      <li>These Terms shall be governed and construed in accordance with the laws of Delaware, United States, without regard to its conflict of law provisions.</li>
      <li>Our failure to enforce any right or provision of these Terms will not be considered a waiver of those rights. If any provision of these Terms is held to be invalid or unenforceable by a court, the remaining provisions of these Terms will remain in effect. These Terms constitute the entire agreement between us regarding our Service, and supersede and replace any prior agreements we might have had between us regarding the Service.</li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="faq-main-block">
     <div class="faq-main-question"><span><span>2.6.</span> Question 2.6. General Provisions</span></div>
     <div class="faq-block">
     <div class="gender-faq-inner-block">
     <div class="gender-faq-content">
      <ul class="gender-faq-content">
      <li>Answer 1.1.</li>
      <li>These Terms shall be governed and construed in accordance with the laws of Delaware, United States, without regard to its conflict of law provisions.</li>
      <li>Our failure to enforce any right or provision of these Terms will not be considered a waiver of those rights. If any provision of these Terms is held to be invalid or unenforceable by a court, the remaining provisions of these Terms will remain in effect. These Terms constitute the entire agreement between us regarding our Service, and supersede and replace any prior agreements we might have had between us regarding the Service.</li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- PAGE 3 : Fruits FAQ's -->
  <div class="faq-main-container faq-main-container-button-3">
   <ul>
    <li>
    <h2 class="faq-title blue_hdr">3. Title 3</h2>
    
    <div class="faq-main-block">
     <div class="faq-main-question"><span><span>3.1.</span> Question 3.1. General Provisions</span></div>
     <div class="faq-block">
     <div class="gender-faq-inner-block">
     <div class="gender-faq-content">
      <ul class="gender-faq-content">
      <li>Answer 1.1.</li>
      <li>These Terms shall be governed and construed in accordance with the laws of Delaware, United States, without regard to its conflict of law provisions.</li>
      <li>Our failure to enforce any right or provision of these Terms will not be considered a waiver of those rights. If any provision of these Terms is held to be invalid or unenforceable by a court, the remaining provisions of these Terms will remain in effect. These Terms constitute the entire agreement between us regarding our Service, and supersede and replace any prior agreements we might have had between us regarding the Service.</li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="faq-main-block">
     <div class="faq-main-question"><span><span>3.2.</span> Question 3.2. General Provisions</span></div>
     <div class="faq-block">
     <div class="gender-faq-inner-block">
     <div class="gender-faq-content">
      <ul class="gender-faq-content">
      <li>Answer 1.1.</li>
      <li>These Terms shall be governed and construed in accordance with the laws of Delaware, United States, without regard to its conflict of law provisions.</li>
      <li>Our failure to enforce any right or provision of these Terms will not be considered a waiver of those rights. If any provision of these Terms is held to be invalid or unenforceable by a court, the remaining provisions of these Terms will remain in effect. These Terms constitute the entire agreement between us regarding our Service, and supersede and replace any prior agreements we might have had between us regarding the Service.</li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="faq-main-block">
     <div class="faq-main-question"><span><span>3.3.</span> Question 3.3. General Provisions</span></div>
     <div class="faq-block">
     <div class="gender-faq-inner-block">
     <div class="gender-faq-content">
      <ul class="gender-faq-content">
      <li>Answer 1.1.</li>
      <li>These Terms shall be governed and construed in accordance with the laws of Delaware, United States, without regard to its conflict of law provisions.</li>
      <li>Our failure to enforce any right or provision of these Terms will not be considered a waiver of those rights. If any provision of these Terms is held to be invalid or unenforceable by a court, the remaining provisions of these Terms will remain in effect. These Terms constitute the entire agreement between us regarding our Service, and supersede and replace any prior agreements we might have had between us regarding the Service.</li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="faq-main-block">
     <div class="faq-main-question"><span><span>3.4.</span> Question 3.4. General Provisions</span></div>
     <div class="faq-block">
     <div class="gender-faq-inner-block">
     <div class="gender-faq-content">
      <ul class="gender-faq-content">
      <li>Answer 1.1.</li>
      <li>These Terms shall be governed and construed in accordance with the laws of Delaware, United States, without regard to its conflict of law provisions.</li>
      <li>Our failure to enforce any right or provision of these Terms will not be considered a waiver of those rights. If any provision of these Terms is held to be invalid or unenforceable by a court, the remaining provisions of these Terms will remain in effect. These Terms constitute the entire agreement between us regarding our Service, and supersede and replace any prior agreements we might have had between us regarding the Service.</li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="faq-main-block">
     <div class="faq-main-question"><span><span>3.5.</span> Question 3.5. General Provisions</span></div>
     <div class="faq-block">
     <div class="gender-faq-inner-block">
     <div class="gender-faq-content">
      <ul class="gender-faq-content">
      <li>Answer 1.1.</li>
      <li>These Terms shall be governed and construed in accordance with the laws of Delaware, United States, without regard to its conflict of law provisions.</li>
      <li>Our failure to enforce any right or provision of these Terms will not be considered a waiver of those rights. If any provision of these Terms is held to be invalid or unenforceable by a court, the remaining provisions of these Terms will remain in effect. These Terms constitute the entire agreement between us regarding our Service, and supersede and replace any prior agreements we might have had between us regarding the Service.</li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="faq-main-block">
     <div class="faq-main-question"><span><span>3.6.</span> Question 3.6. General Provisions</span></div>
     <div class="faq-block">
     <div class="gender-faq-inner-block">
     <div class="gender-faq-content">
      <ul class="gender-faq-content">
      <li>Answer 1.1.</li>
      <li>These Terms shall be governed and construed in accordance with the laws of Delaware, United States, without regard to its conflict of law provisions.</li>
      <li>Our failure to enforce any right or provision of these Terms will not be considered a waiver of those rights. If any provision of these Terms is held to be invalid or unenforceable by a court, the remaining provisions of these Terms will remain in effect. These Terms constitute the entire agreement between us regarding our Service, and supersede and replace any prior agreements we might have had between us regarding the Service.</li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- SECTION 5 : NO INFORMATION PAGE BASE ON SEARCH INPUT -->
  <div id="no-information-container">
   <div id="no-information">Sorry! We have no information.</div>
   <button id="clear-button">Clear Search</button>
  </div>
  </div>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У тебя id кнопки не правильно прописан был. Вот код для показа второго раздела при клике на button-1:

```
$("#button-1").click(function() {
  $('.faq-main-container-button-1').hide();
  $('.faq-main-container-button-2').show();
  $('.faq-main-container-button-3').hide();
});
```

Аналогично для других кнопок можно сделать. Для кнопки all просто показываешь все блоки.

Лучше конструкцию вида $('.faq-main-container-button-1') вынести в отдельную переменную например var butt1 = $('.faq-main-container-button-1'), и обращаться к блокам через переменные.

И именуй классы, id, переменные в одном стиле, чтобы таких ошибок не делать

Comment: Точно. Спасибо! Глупая ошибка конечно.